# How to check if you're on the last page of paged single post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've tried this code but it doesn't check when using the

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

quicktag to add page links to break up a long single post

I tried the following code however it seems to only work for paginated archives.

```
global $wp_query;
$current_page = $wp_query->get( 'paged' );
if ( ! $current_page ) {
    $current_page = 1;
}
if ( $current_page == $wp_query->max_num_pages ) {
    // You are on the last page
}
```

What i need to do is check for the last page of a paged single post which uses the WordPress quicktag